# Sed error: 'unescaped newline inside substitute pattern' and 'bad flag in substitute command'

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, plist

#### Question:

I am new in sed，so when I excute following code in shell:

```
sed -e "/^\s<key>CHANNEL_NAME<\/key>$/{N;s/\(^\s<string>\).+\(<\/string>$\)/\1test\2}" Info.plist > test.plist
```

Sed give me an error: "sed: 1: "/^\sCHANNEL_NAME<\ ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern"

My Question: What does "unescaped newline inside substitute pattern" exactly mean?

The Info.plist file is like this:

```
...
<key>CHANNEL_NAME</key>
<string>App Store</string>
...
```

I am appreciate everyone could answer the question, thanks!

---

#### Anwser:

Thanks @potong @dogbane @Beta ! : )

Because it is a Cocoa plist, so here's my finally solution:

```
sed '/<key>CHANNEL_NAME<\/key>/{N;s/\(<string>\).*\(<\/string>\)/\1test\2/;}' Info.plist > test.plist
```

#### Tips:

1. I got two error during my process to solve the problem. Put them here:

   - sed: 1: "/^\sCHANNEL_NAME<\ ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
   - sed: 1: "/CHANNEL_NAME</ke ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'
2. I make so many mistakes in the first code.

   - haven't escaped the '+'
   - should end with 2/}"
   - acturally should end with 2/;}" (I miss a ';', so I got the second error in Tips 1)
3. user 'n' or 'N' both works for me.
4. Probably because of on Mac, the '.+' (even if I escaped) not work, so have to change it as @potong said, '..*'

Any good advice to approve the code is welcome, thanks all the following guys again!

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. But you have other problems with your `sed` expression. You haven't escaped the `+` and there is a missing slash to terminate the `s` command i.e. it should end with `2/}"`.

Comment: @dogbane Thank you very much. It's a mistake input but the problem is not expression. En, What's your os? Linux or Mac?

Comment: I *can* reproduce the error (on Mac), and when I correct the `+` and terminate the command with `2/;}`, the substitution works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/^\s*<key>CHANNEL_NAME<\/key>$/{n;s/^\(\s*<string>\).\+\(<\/string>\)$/\1test\2/}' Info.plist > test.plist
```

N.B. You should allow for whitespace (`^\s*`) at the beginning of a line and print the matched line before comparing the start of the next line for the substitution command i.e. use `n` instead of `N`.

Or:

```
sed -e '/^ *<key>CHANNEL_NAME<\/key>$/!b' -e 'n' -e 's/^\( *<string>\)..*\(<\/string>\)$/\1test\2/' Info.plist > test.plist
```

Comment: I tried your advice but still cant make it right. I think it maybe because of Mac OS, but not sure. Thanks all the save

Comment: @kimimaro I've added a more generic solution (removed the `\s` and `\+` metacharacters). However this does not account for tabs.

Comment: Your answer is useful! Because of my context is a cocoa plist, so probably then most nearly answer is my own answer following my question, but you have solve my problem. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you're just learning sed: sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else just use awk.

Here's a GNU awk solution (you can cram it onto one line if you like):

```
$ cat file
...
foo
<key>CHANNEL_NAME</key>
<string>App Store</string>
...
$
$ awk '
   found { $0=gensub(/(<string>).*(<\/string>)/,"\\1test\\2",""); found=0 }
   /<key>CHANNEL_NAME<\/key>/ { found=1 }
   { print $0 }
' file
...
foo
<key>CHANNEL_NAME</key>
<string>test</string>
...
```

It doesn't LOOK much different from the sed solution, but just try modifying the sed solution to do *anything* additional e.g. add line numbers to the output:

```
$ awk '
   found { $0=gensub(/(<string>).*(<\/string>)/,"\\1test\\2",""); found=0 }
   /<key>CHANNEL_NAME<\/key>/ { found=1 }
   { print NR, $0 }
' file
1 ...
2 foo
3 <key>CHANNEL_NAME</key>
4 <string>test</string>
5 ...
```

or replace the text between "string"s with the contents of the line before CHANNEL_NAME instead of the hard-coded "test":

```
awk '
   found { $0=gensub(/(<string>).*(<\/string>)/,"\\1" rep "\\2",""); found=0 }
   /<key>CHANNEL_NAME<\/key>/ { found=1; rep=prev }
   { print $0; prev=$0 }
' file
...
foo
<key>CHANNEL_NAME</key>
<string>foo</string>
...
```

and you'll find you need a whole other solution, probably involving a nightmarish concoction of single letters and punctuation marks, whereas with awk it's a simple tweak to enhance your starting solution.